# python xpath: single quotationmarks and double quotationmarks

Tags: python, xpath

I hope this is a small problem:

I want to search for a text, that can contain doublequotes " and/or singelquotes '. Now I can use this:

```
"//a[contains(text(), '"+ mytext +"')]"
```

or this:

```
'//a[contains(text(), "'+ mytext +'")]'
```

but if i have mytext is something like this:

```
a'b"c
```

i get (of course) a xpath-error (Invalid XPath-Expression). How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 2):

In XPath 2.0 the delimiting quotes of a string literal can be included in the literal by doubling: `"He said, ""I can't"""`.

In XPath 1.0, such a string can't be written as a literal, but it can be expressed using concat(): `concat("He said, ", '"', "I can't", '"')`

Of course, if such an XPath expression is then to be written as a string literal in a host language such as Python, the quotes must be further escaped according to Python rules.

Comment: For use in Selenium (an XPath 1.0 application), I actually wrote an escape-quotes-splitting-into-concat()-arguments routine.  It was easier to write than it is to describe :-)

Answer (score -1):

Use Python triple quotes r"""a'b"c""". Inside the xpath, use an escape  .

Comment: I tried this:

`mytext = mytext.replace('"', '"""')`

`link = sess.at_xpath('//a[contains(text(), "'+ mytext +'")]')`

but I still get the xpath-error.

And how do I escape inside the xpath?